# Berry Esseen type result for probability density functions

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

Let $X_1, X_2, \cdots$ be i.i.d. random variables with $E(X_1) = 0, E(X_1^2) = \sigma^2 >0, E(|X_1|^3) = \rho < \infty$.
Let $Y_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ and let us note $F_n$ (resp. $\Phi$) the *cumulative distribution function* of $\frac{Y_n \sqrt{n}}{\sigma}$ (resp. of the standard normal distribution).
Then, Berry Esseen theorem states that there exists a positive constant $C$ such that for all $x$ and $n$,
$$|F_n(x)-\Phi(x)| \leq \frac{C \rho}{\sigma^3 \sqrt{n}}.$$

Are there known conditions on the distribution of $X_1$ that allow to derive a similar statement for *probability density functions* instead of cumulative distribution functions?

Comment: Sure. Look, e.g., at the supplements to chapter VII in the classical book "Sums of independent random variables" by Petrov.

Comment: ok, thanks! I just need to find a copy of the book...

Comment: Hum. If you search for
"Sums of independent random variables" Petrov
on google.com, you should find what you need on the first page of results ;) ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The magic words are "local limit theorem".

Comment: Are there local limit theorems with explicit constants like Berry Esseen? I have "Normal Approximation and Asymptotic Expansions" by Bhattacharya and Rao, and all the local limit theorems seem to be assymptotic or with unspecified constants.