# Multidimensional Berry–Esseen for probability density functions

Tags: st.statistics, reference-request, pr.probability

This is a follow up to this recent question: [Berry Esseen type result for probability density functions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/75829)

There exists a *multidimensional* version of the usual Berry–Esseen theorem (for cumulative distribution functions), see for example this paper of 1945 by Bergström "[On the central limit theorem in the space $R_k$, $k > 1$](https://doi.org/10.1080/03461238.1945.10404921)". Skand. Aktuarie Tidskr. 28, 106–127. [Zbl 0060.28708](https://zbmath.org/0060.28708)

There also exists a *local limit* version of the Berry–Esseen theorem for probability density functions: see for instance chapter VII of the book "[Sums of independent random variables](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-65809-9)" by Petrov.

I was not able, however, to find a multidimensional version of this local limit theorem. Does such a result appear somewhere in the literature?

Many thanks!

Edit (October 22):
I've found a partial answer in this paper of Ričardas Zitikis:
"[A Berry – Esséen bound for multivariate $L$-estimates with explicit dependence on dimension](https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0084498)". In: Kalashnikov, V.V., Zolatarev, V.M. (eds) Stability Problems for Stochastic Models. Lecture Notes in Mathematics, vol 1546. Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg. [Zbl 0804.60023](https://zbmath.org/0804.60023)

In this paper, a bound is provided (Theorem 1.2) but still depends on a *universal constant* $c$. It would still be great to known an upper bound on $c$.

Comment: I don't know of a precise reference, but mathscinet returns a large number of papers on this topic (many in russian, though). I don't have access to these journals, so I can't check, but looking at the first page of http://springerlink.com/content/v7071t24g455837h, it might contain something relevant...

Comment: @Yvan Velenik Thanks a lot! I don't have access to mathscinet but I found the paper you mentioned: it can be downloaded here perso.telecom-paristech.fr/~leverrie/Rozowski.pdf However, there are many notations which are obscure for me, and I'm wondering if there exists some more modern treatment of the question somewhere. 

Comment: The link to `springerlink.com` in a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78011/multidimensional-berry-esseen-for-probability-density-functions#comment199628_78011) above seems to be broken. The alternative link at `perso.telecom-paristech.fr` in another [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78011/multidimensional-berry-esseen-for-probability-density-functions#comment200649_78011) above also seems to be broken. I'm unable to find any snapshots saved on the Wayback Machine.